# How do I show UITextField data on a UILabel in a second UIViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'd like to pass through the data entered into the `UITextFields` in the current view controller to a second view controller on the save button action. I'm using storyboards, could anyone advise me on how to achieve this? I'm using Xcode 6.

```
@IBAction func SAVEButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let viewcontroller = SecondViewController();
    viewcontroller.name = self.nametextfield.text;
    viewcontroller.phone = self.phonetextfield.text;
    viewcontroller.city = self.citytextfield.text;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: If you are using Navigation Controller. Pass the value in ' prepareForSegue ' method.

Comment: @kampai same methods i tried i'm not getting that's why i'm asking .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found my Problem**

```
@IBAction func SAVEButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

let viewcontroller = SecondViewController();
viewcontroller.name = self.nametextfield.text;
viewcontroller.phone = self.phonetextfield.text;
viewcontroller.city = self.citytextfield.text;

}
```

problem with this line **let viewcontroller = SecondViewController()**

i changed it to

let viewcontroller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondviewController

With This change My code working fine thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `FirstViewController`,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    If ([destinationVC isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {

        SecondViewController *viewcontroller = (SecondViewController *)destinationVC;
        viewcontroller.name = self.nametextfield.text;
        viewcontroller.phone = self.phonetextfield.text;
        viewcontroller.city = self.citytextfield.text;
    }
}
```

Assuming that you have only one segue to `SecondViewController`.
If you have multiple segue to `SecondViewController` then you can check segue identifier instead of `isKindOfClass` check.

Comment: i am remove segue . i want in push method

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will not work because your views will not be initialized until `viewDidLoad:` is executed. Basically, you're assigning values to nil objects.

You either need to add string properties that you later assign to your view elements in `viewDidLoad` or do what Akhilrajtr mentioned if you are using a segue for your transition.

Answer (score 0):

pass the data between VC create a intent for destination VC,like below

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewcontroller.name = self.nametextfield.text;
    viewcontroller.phone = self.phonetextfield.text;
    viewcontroller.city = self.citytextfield.text;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: i am tried  your code but it shows     ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: but it's worked for me.i don't know exact reason check the file's owners,if yellow triangles are shown click the cross (X) to remove the yellow triangles.